# How to return index page for all requests?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my project, I decided to use Spring boot on the server side and React on the client side. Page navigation should be performed on the client using React-router. One of the conditions of the router is that each request to server must return an index.html page.  I have an index.html in `/resources/static/` folder and Spring boot use it for `/` and `/index` requests. Also this folder contains resources such as JS and CSS folders and files. But I want to use `index.html` for all requests (e.g. `http://my.domain/unknown/page/`) except `http://my.domain/static/**` because this path for client-side application.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should rather redirect `301` all requests to `/` and return index.html on `/`. `301` means permanent redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution will be to redirect all request to a certain page e.g. `/` and return `index.html` on `/` page. This can be done on your server engine configuration.